# setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) error

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android.
I read some books. I create checkbox

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
CheckBox cb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.mycheckbox);
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        cb.setText("Checked");
    } else {
        cb.setText("UnCheck");
    }
}
```

}

When use cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); android studio error:
setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) in CompoundButton cannot be applied (anonymous android.view.View.onClickListener)

If i change code such as:

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        //do stuff

    }
});
```

Then ok

Can you help me. i want to use "this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` :

```
 cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Because in current code  `this` refer to the Button `onClick` method context instead of `MainActivity` class  in which `OnCheckedChangeListener` interface in implemented.